# How do I define and call a generic function parameter in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm looking for the one-argument typesafe equivalent of `Function.prototype.call` in Typescript.

This does not work, because `F` is missing the proper constraint (perhaps):

```
function call<F,A>(f: F, arg: A) {
  return f(arg);
}
```

Thus, Typescript complains "This expression is not callable. Type 'unknown' has no call signatures."

How do I make `F` callable? How do I manage `call` to have the return type of `F`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you said, you'll need to add a constraint so it's callable. One option may look like the following:

```js
function call<F extends Function,A>(f: F, arg: A) {
  return f(arg);
}
```

Generic Constraints: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints.

If you wanted to provide stronger type safety one approach may look like the following.

```js
type Parameter<T> = T extends (arg: infer T) => any ? T : never;


function call<F extends (arg: any) => any>(f: F, arg: Parameter<F>): ReturnType<F> {
  return f(arg);
}

const fn = (input: number): number => input * 2;

const result = call(fn, 2) // Valid
const result2 = call(fn, "2") // Argument of type '"2"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.(2345)
const result3 = call(fn, false) // Argument of type 'false' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.(2345)

const badFn = (input: number, options: {}): number => input * 2;

const result4 = call(badFn, 2) // Argument of type '(input: number, options: {}) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(arg: any) => any'.(2345)
```

This defines a more strict constraint for `F`, saying it must be a function that accepts only one argument. The argument is then inferred from that function. You could also use `Parameters<F>[0]` since [`Parameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterst) is a utility type provided by Typescript. `ReturnType` is another utility type to infer the return type of `F` which can be used as the return type of `call`.

Comment: Ah, is `Function` described in the Typescript docs somewhere? And: `call` returns `any` now. Can I make it typesafe?

Comment: @mkluwe I updated with an example with stronger type-safety

Comment: Ok, answer accepted. I did a small getting rid of specifying the return type, if you don't mind.