# I am giving the generic type to the function parameter, when i call the function it gives me an error

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I am giving the generic type to the function parameter, when I call the function it gives me an error "This expression is not callable. Type unknown has no call signature"

```
function a() { return 'abc' }

function fun<T>(x: T, y: string) {
        return x() + y;
    }

fun(a, "str")
```

Comment: You're not specifying that `T` is of a callable type so `Type 'unknown' has no call signatures.`  You need to specify that T is callable `function fun<T extends Function>` or a more specific function type as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62233415/3262937 you should use `T extends Function` so that the Typescript compiler knows that you generic parameter is a Function.

See this playground:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwBQEpEG9ECcCmUIuSA5MgEYSmIC+AUPaJLAoswDwAqi+AHlHxgAJgGdEAMXDR4YAHyo+ALkRcANIgCeK0VFwwwAc0xZ6icxfMEiJRHwyIA1FoDcZiwybhUyDQCJdXD90IA

Comment: If the answer is just "see this other answer," then it should be a vote to close as duplicate, not an answer. (And I think you're right, that other question does cover this ground, so good find.)

Answer (score -2):

There is the solution.

```
function a() { return 'abc' }

function fun<T>(x: T, y: string) {
        return x + y;
    }

fun(a(), "str");
```